# How did my ASPX page become UTF-8? I didn't ask for it

Tags: visual-studio-2008, utf-8

Yesterday, after a minor markup edit to an aspx page, I was checking the file(s) back into TFS 2005 when I got the message that, "The file encoding has changed from ANSI to UTF-8.  Checking the file in with this encoding will cause problems with Compares, etc." or words to that effect.

Helpfully, the dialog gave the options 'OK' and 'Help' -- effectively forcing me to check-in with the 'bad' change.

My question is, how did this occur?  I have not changed any settings in VSTS to cause this (that I know about).

Thanks for any help -- Jon

Comment: Heh, guerilla future proofing.

Answer (score 1):

That's typically happened to me when I've been working with an offshore team.  VS uses your local setting whenever you update something so you'll see this if someone else uses a different encoding pretty much always.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you were using a different editor on the file than the one that created it? Your editor may default to saving files in UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1/etc.

If this is the case, check your editor settings and change the default file encoding to the one used in the majority of your project.

Comment: I have been unable to find such a setting in any environment that might have been involved; even accidentally.

Thanks for the pointer.